# DBConnect::prepare() Error When Trying to Insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm messing with PDO and I'm trying to insert some data into my table; however, I'm getting a `DBConnect::prepare()` error.

Here's my insertcard.php file:

```
<?php

  require_once "connection.php";

  $Name = $_POST['cardname'];
  $Colour = $_POST['colour'];
  $Rarity = $_POST['rarity'];

  $CardQuery = "INSERT INTO `cards`(`Name`, `Colour`, `Rarity`) VALUES (`:Name`,`:Colour`,`:Rarity`)";

  $CardResult = $dbconnection->prepare($CardQuery);
  $CardExec = $CardResult->execute(array(":Name"=>$Name,":Colour"=>$Colour,":Rarity"=>$Rarity));

  if ($CardExec) {
    Echo "Data Inserted!";
  }

?>
```

And my function in connection.php that connects to my database:

```
private function Connect() {

  try {
    $db = $this->Connection = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->hostname . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . '', $this->username, $this->password);
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "<br>Wow, we done goofed.";
  }

  }
```

And instantiated by:

```
$dbconnection = new DBConnect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cardtest');
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?  I'll show more of the connection.php file if need be.

Comment: You're blindly going without checking for errors, so you can't see that you have a syntax error. With bound parameters, you don't need to quote your values.

Comment: (`:Name`,`:Colour`,`:Rarity`) change to (:Name, :Colour, :Rarity)

Comment: @aynber I'm not blindly going, I didn't know that bound parameters shouldn't be quoted.  That being said, I changed it to:

  `$CardQuery = "INSERT INTO `cards` (`Name`, `Colour`, `Rarity`) VALUES (:Name, :Colour, :Rarity)";`

And it still doesn't work.

Comment: still you need to [check for errors](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors)